# Recover a malfuncioning Windows 10 in a dual boot computer

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, filesystems, multi-boot

Background: I have a Windows 10+Ubuntu dual boot with a big common partition for files.

Trying to fix a problem with Microsoft office installation I messed with my Windows 10. I don't know what happened exactly but now Windows act very weirdly. For instance, while I interact with the start bar or navigate through windows there are strange flickering and frequent freezes. I can connect to my wifi only before to log and even after that I have the lan icon instead of the wifi icon. Weird as I said. I am afraid the registry is interested (idiotically I interacted with it without doing a backup before).

So: I checked for a recovery point. There aren't. At this point I don't know what to do. Using the "reset this pc" and "go back to an earlier build" recovery options in windows 10 would create problems to Ubuntu am I right? There is a solution that doesn't involve reset my computer completely?

I runned sfc/ scannow, the system found not-fixable files. This is the content of the sfcdetails.txt with just the stuff that created problems.
[sfc_cleaned][1]

This is the complete version instead [sfc_original](http://pastebin.com/DqJSfig3)

UPDATE
I runned DISM and this was the result

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.14393.0

Image Version: 10.0.14393.0

[==========================100.0%==========================] The restore operation completed successfully.
The operation completed successfully.
```

This instead is the content of the log file
[dism.log](http://pastebin.com/cr6K3e5a)

Comment: It would not.  Those features only touch the Windows partition.  Why are you using SFC instead of DISM to repair your Windows installation?

Comment: I tried DISM and it didn't solved the problem. Nevertheless, after a little research, I found there are a lot of variation of the code. Which one should i use?
I upgraded Windows 10 from the original version to Anniversary recently should I use
'DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:C:\$Windows.~BT\Sources\Install.esd'?

Comment: No;  You should get rid of the directory infact by running the Cleanup Tool.  You cannot mount an ESD, but its not clear, the reason you want to mount a source in the first place.

Comment: "I tried DISM and it didn't solved the problem." - When you say this, does this mean it reported no corruption, or it was unable to fix the corruption it detected or it just bombed and gave an error?

Comment: It reported no corruption but I don't remember the exact code I used maybe it was the wrong one.

About my previous comment I was thinking to use that code following this guide [http://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-dism-command-line-utility-repair-windows-10-image] but I don't know how much this is reliable. That's why I am asking.

Comment: If you can't tell me which command you used, I can't answer your follow-up questions, update your question when you have that information.  Provide the results of that command, log file is generated when you run DISM, provide us that log file.

Comment: [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](http://superuser.com/search?tab=votes&q=Dism%20%2fOnline%20%2fCleanup-Image%20%2fRestoreHealth).....[Windows 10 DISM](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html)

Comment: Runned and updated. Sorry for the delay; today I needed the computer for work.

Comment: Any damage that did exist has been repaired based on the output of the command, the log, can't follow it since it isn't in English.  Running SFC likely would be successful at this point, of course, its also not required.  Of course what "behavior" your trying to fix, specifically outside of the fact SFC wasn't working, isn't clear by the information you submitted.

Comment: So what should I do?

Comment: Clarify the question?  Your SFC logs indicate all files were repair.  The files in the other SFC log that could not be repair are **shortcuts**.  Your DISM file is not in English, but based on the output, all indications all corruption was fixed.  I can't submit an answer to a question, where I don't even know, what the question is

Comment: I solved the problem just using the reset function of Windows 10 (with the option of keeping my files). As you said it didn't affect in any way my Ubuntu installation. Even the grub remained intact.
Thank you for the help.